# AccountPicker error on Android 2.3.3

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an Android application that uses Google Oauth2 signin.
To prompt the user for an account i'm using AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent().

This relies on Google Play Services being available on the device, so in my activity's onResume() i'm running the following check as per the google documentation:

```
// Check that Google Play Services are available on the device
// We use them to show the account picker dialog
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

if(status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){     
    if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(status)){
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, REQUESTID_PLAY_SERVICES).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.purchases_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
}
```

This works great on my Jellybean device however when trying it on an older device running Android 2.3.3 (Gingerbread) i'm getting the following exception.

Has anybody ever seen this before?

```
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906): Error: Unable to resume activity {com.somecompany.someapp/com.somecompany.someapp.activities.PurchaseActivity}: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle 'com.google.android.gms.common.strings.GmsStrings_en_US', key ''
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.somecompany.someapp/com.somecompany.someapp.activities.PurchaseActivity}: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle 'com.google.android.gms.common.strings.GmsStrings_en_US', key ''
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906):       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2460)
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906):       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906):       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1847)
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906):       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906):       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906):       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906):       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906):       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906):       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906):       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906):       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906): Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle 'com.google.android.gms.common.strings.GmsStrings_en_US', key ''
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906):       at java.util.ResourceBundle.missingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:225)
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906):       at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:218)
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906):       at com.sonelli.y.a(Unknown Source)
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906):       at com.sonelli.y.a(Unknown Source)
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906):       at com.sonelli.h.a(Unknown Source)
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906):       at com.somecompany.someapp.activities.PurchaseActivity.onResume(PurchaseActivity.java:49)
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906):       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1242)
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906):       at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3957)
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906):       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
E/Activities/MainActivity( 1906):       ... 12 more
~
```

Comment: your error occurs for this option :: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle 'com.google.android.gms.common.strings.GmsStrings_en_US', key ''

Comment: Did you define any a string key GmsStrings_en_US in an API specific folder in your project? If you did, then that key will not be available to API levels less than that version. Follow the stacktrace lines: at com.sonelli.y.a(Unknown Source)
at com.sonelli.y.a(Unknown Source)
at com.sonelli.h.a(Unknown Source)
at com.somecompany.someapp.activities.PurchaseActivity.onResume(PurchaseActivity.java:49)